# Images not showing after changing wp-content folder name

Tags: plugins, images, errors

I renamed the `wp-content` folder to `hamza` with the **ithemes plugin**. But now images are showing error on the website. When I try to rename it back to `wp-content` through itheme plugin, it shows failure notification.

I also renamed it back to `wp-content` manually but the problem is still not solved. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The safe way to change `wp-content` folder, is the following:

First, define the new `wp-content` name in your `wp-config.php` file:

`define ('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'hamza');`

Then, define the new path for images, style, scripts, etc:

`define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME) ;`

`define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);`

This will allow your plugins and other stuff to be notified about the change of your `wp-content` folder.

You might also want to define your site URL too if the above wasn't sufficient:

`define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');`

Comment: +1, but please remember, hard coded images will still need to be redirected in `.htaccess`, or in server configuration or replaced in Database or files.

Comment: Yes. I assumed that his images are coded relatively through WP's core.

Comment: That's if everyone followed best practice. However, image already uploaded will have hard links in the Database. That's how WP works.